# Can't Return Null so I need to substitute

Tags: mysql

I have a nice query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( p.id ), 
               p.last_name, 
               p.first_name,
               c.club_name, 
               c.join_date, 
               e.Full_name
FROM   people AS p, 
       club AS c, 
       employee AS e 
WHERE  c.people_id = p.id 
       AND p.id_ofproducer = e.id 
       AND size IN ( 'Large', 'Medium' )
```

It almost does what I expect it to do.   Wish to alter this so that I get All the records where size is Medium or Large regardless of where there is a Club (c) or EMployee (e) related record.

AND:  I Would really like then   c.club_name,  c.join_date,  and.or  e.Full_name  to come back as "--" if they are NULL.

So my question is two fold.

1. Whats wrong with my SQL/Join
2. Is it possible to return a string in lieu of Null?

Comment: Not apropos to your question, but your use of `DISTINCT` in this query is both expensive and ineffective.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer 1:** Your join is an `INNER JOIN` meaning it has to be in both tables, you need to switch to `LEFT JOIN`.
**Answer 2:** Yes, using `IFNULL(c.club_name,'--')` or `COALESCE(c.club_name,'--')`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT( p.id ), 
               p.last_name, 
               p.first_name,
               IFNULL(c.club_name,'--') AS club_name, 
               IFNULL(c.join_date,'--') AS join_date, 
               IFNULL(e.Full_name,'--') AS Full_name
FROM   people AS p, 
       LEFT JOIN club AS c ON c.people_id = p.id
       LEFT JOIN employee AS e ON p.id_ofproducer = e.id 
WHERE  size IN ( 'Large', 'Medium' )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your join is that it's a `INNER` join and you need a `LEFT` join. Also, it's best to use the ANSI join syntax rather than burying the join conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

As for transforming a NULL into a string, use the MySQL [Coalesce function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

The new query would look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( p.id ), 
           p.last_name, 
           p.first_name,
           COALESCE(c.club_name, '---'),
           COALESCE(c.join_date, '---'),
           COALESCE(e.Full_name, '---')
FROM   people AS p
LEFT JOIN club c ON p.id = c.people_id
LEFT JOIN employee e ON p.id_ofproducer = e.id
WHERE size IN ('Large', 'Medium')
```

I'm not quite sure what's going on with the `DISTINCT(p.id)` but if whatever it's doing works for you then it's all good.

Comment: FWIW, both join styles are ANSI.  The comma-style syntax is in SQL-89 and supported by later revision for backward compatibility.  The `JOIN` syntax is in SQL-92 up to current revisions.

Comment: Thanks Bill - I never knew that. I've tried here and there to find a definitive description of what exactly is the ANSI standard, but other than the expensive ANSI-sponsored documents I've come up empty. So I've been piecing it together bit by bit, and nuggets like this help immensely. Again, thanks!

Comment: A good book is "SQL-99 Complete, Really" which has been adapted to an online version:  https://kb.askmonty.org/en/sql-99/

Comment: @EdGibbs, IFNULL would probably be better in this case as you are only dealing with 2 values and COALESCE is for returning the first non-null in the list: http://doinglines.com/post/uncategorized/mysql-ifnull-and-coalesce-for-template-processing

Comment: Probably so. I tend to use Coalesce because it works the same in MySQL, Oracle and SQL Server so it's one less thing to learn :)

Comment: @EdGibbs, fair enough, and compatibility is always a good reason.  I tend to opt for more compatible approaches to make migration easier, just never had to do something like IFNULL or COALESCE in a DB other than MySQL...  Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Use *left* joins and `ifnull()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, 
       p.last_name, 
       p.first_name,
       ifnull(c.club_name, '--') club_name, 
       ifnull(c.join_date, '--') join_date,
       ifnull(e.Full_name, '--') Full_name
FROM  people p
LEFT JOIN 0club c c.people_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN employee e ON p.id_ofproducer = e.id 
WHERE size IN ( 'Large', 'Medium' )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Use LEFT OUTER JOIN
2. Use ifnull() function

    SELECT DISTINCT( p.id ), 
                       p.last_name, 
                       p.first_name,
                       ifnull(c.club_name, '--') as club_name,
                       ifnull(c.join_date, '--') as join_date,
                       ifnull(e.Full_name, '--') as Full_name
        FROM   people AS p 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN club AS c ON c.people_id = p.id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN employee AS e ON p.id_ofproducer = e.id
        WHERE  size IN ( 'Large', 'Medium' )
```